# initializer not constant?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Quick question if I may: I am just curious about the following (see below) Xcode says "initializer element is not constant" why this does not work, I guess its the NSArray ...

```
static NSArray *stuffyNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ted",@"Dog",@"Snosa",nil];
```

and this does ...

```
static NSString *stuffyNames[3] = {@"Ted",@"Dog",@"Snosa"};
```

gary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you are called a method (+ arrayWithObjects) that returns data - although the result is immutable, its actually dynamically generated data.

Answer (score 3):

Static local variables are initialized at **compile** time so their initializer must also be known at compile time, which is obviously not true in you 1st example.

> Static variables may be initialized in
>   their declarations; however, the
>   initializers must be constant
>   expressions, and initialization is
>   done only once at compile time when
>   memory is allocated for the static
>   variable.

and [more](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.6.html) on static variables.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's the `NSArray`. Think about what happens at compile time.

In the second case it has all the information it needs. It has three `NSString` constants and a C-style array to put them in.

On your first line you have a call to a class method with four parameters, all of which happen to be constants. As far as the compiler is concerned, `NSArray` is no different from, say, `UIApplication`. It's a class with paramters. You and I know that it's an array but the implementation of that is in the Foundation library and not a core part of the language.